# Force Firefox to Visit Certain URLs on Alternative Port (not 80)

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to force Firefox (I have 6.0.2 currently) to request a website on an alternative port? I do some upgrades to a Drupal site for a client, and they have their Varnish server configured to only allow work on their development site to be done on port 8008. So I visit http://www.sitename.com:8008.

What I want is a setting (possibly in firefox?) to always redirect requests for this specific URL to port 8008.

Or would this be set in my HOSTS file on the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a firefox addon called ReDirector for this, it can be found at:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/

It uses regex to define the rules of url rewriting.

Best regards.